# Help with Algebra Manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, z-transform

I have an expression which I need to simplify:
$$TF = K \frac{(1+z^{-1})}{(1-0.75z^{-1})(1+0.5z^{-1})}z^{-1}$$

I want to rationalize this and get an expression for the poles and zeros.

Any help or suggestions please?

Comment: Whats with the minus 1? Please provide feedback. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\frac{1+\frac{1}{z}}{\left(1-\frac{3}{4z}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2z}\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{z}=\frac{z\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)}{z\left(z-\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{z+1}{z\left(z-\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: If we go back to the original equation. We have, $$TF = \frac{(z^{-1}+z^{-2})}{1-0.25z^{-1}-0.375z^{-2}}$$ If we put this expression in to matlab as tf([0 1 1],[1 -0.25 -0.375],1,'variable','z^-1') then pzmap, we get that there is a zero at -1 and 2 poles. However, your expression suggests that there are 3 poles. Any thoughts on this discrepancy?

Comment: you have forgotten $$z^{-1}$$ in front of the numerator which multiply the denominator by $z$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used it to multiply out the numerator by $z^{-1}$ Is that not ok? Or must I multiply the denominator by $z$ instead?

Comment: it is the same you can multiply the numerator by $z^{-1}$ or the denominator by $z$

Comment: Cool, that was my understanding of what I have done. Hence I have $z^{-1} + z^{-2}$ in the numerator rather than just $1+z^{-1}$. You said I have forgotten $z^{-1}$, but I cant quite see where I have forgotten it?

Comment: I got the same  as you $$\frac{z^{-1}+z^{-2}}{1-0.25z^{-1}-0.375z^{-2}}$$

Comment: Now you can multiply numerator and denominator by $z^2$

Comment: Thanks. If I multiply top and bottom by $z^{2}$ then we have numerator $z+1$ and denominator is a quadratic. However, your original post has a $z^{3}$ in the denominator. Not sure if I am missing something simple here? Sorry for my slowness.